# Online IDE loses ability to run functions when the following code is loaded

Tags: javascript, class, google-apps-script, v8, google-apps-script-editor

I have narrowed the problem or bug to be triggered by either of the two commented lines being uncommitted. I was unable to find any similar questions but somebody else might have better search ability than I do.

Using the new runtime (Chrome V8) I am currently testing how to implement classes to an existing project but this testing is being done in it's own environment.

```
class test{

    //publicFoo = 321;   // <---- these two lines
    //#privateFoo = 456;

    constructor(){
        Logger.log("test created");
        this.foo = 123;   

    }

    getfoo(){
        return this.foo;
    }

    getPrivateFoo(){
        //return this.#privateFoo;
    }

}

function myClassTester(){
        const myTest = new test();

        Logger.log("myTest.foo: " + myTest.foo );
        Logger.log("myTest.getfoo(): " + myTest.getfoo() );
        Logger.log("myTest.publicFoo: " + myTest.publicFoo );
        Logger.log("myTest.privateFoo: " + myTest.privateFoo );
        Logger.log("myTest.getPrivateFoo(): " + myTest.getPrivateFoo() );

}
```

picture, no issues with the lines commented

[image]

picture, no functions to run when un commented

[image]

While verifying to write the question here I have also noticed if you do the edit online vs in clasp it does throw

> Error: Line 3: Unexpected token = (line 2021, file "esprima.browser.js-bundle.js")

on saving...

Link to issue tracker ticket. https://issuetracker.google.com/150896358

Comment: Create a issue in issue tracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: @Kettch - this is not a bug, V8 runtime (at least in how it is used for GAS) does not support public and private class field declarations yet (they are experimental, but are on standards track, so you can expect them to be supported in the future).

Comment: @Oleg If it's not supported, it should throw a error rather than allowing user to complete it, but listing no functions to run later. On that note, it  is still a bug. Furthermore chrome v8 does support  field declarations.

Comment: @TheMaster, yep, I agree that it should throw - though it does so, is it not (not that this msg is very helpful indeed)? Yep, in V8 they are supported, although I don't recall them being explicitly supported in docs regarding V8 [migration](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#classes)

Comment: @Oleg I haven't tested it. But a error is not thrown right? It only fails to list the functions.

Comment: @TheMaster - well, it does throw a bad syntax error for me when using clasp (@Kettch - does it not throw for you, judging from your post?) - just recently overenthusiasticly tried to push a file with class using public field declarations, which resulted in bad syntax and push reject (and it does throw in online editor, though it certainly could use a descriptive error instead of pointing out a generic SyntaxError)

Comment: @TheMaster Ah, that's disappointing. This might be some of my old C practices getting me again. I have been following the V8 documentation as I couldn't find specific gs docs past the migration page.
using clasp there is no error thrown shows as a successful push.
The bad syntax error above I stumbled on when doing a quick edit in the online IDE

Comment: @oleg and TheMaster. Thanks for the comments though. At least I know what the known behavior is.

Comment: @Kettch - dissapointing indeed (it is likely to be added when out of experimental stage). Re: no err - I've retested on one of my projects - indeed no errors in push this time, curious.

Comment: @OlegValter thanks for confirming the clasp part. I've submitted a ticket to their issue tracker but I'm not super familiar with that system. I've linked this thread if it ends up being useful

Comment: Hi @Kettch - could you please also update the question with a link to issue tracker so that others will see it and be able to star it with ease (basically: the  mroe stars the higher the chance it will be addressed quicker). I would suggest this as a feature request, but let's see

Comment: Thanks, @OlegValter slipped my mind there. I think I've grabbed a public link to it. Feel free to add any comments or corrections.

Comment: Thanks, @Kettch, so for now the only way is to avoid fields for a while)

Comment: Hi! could you guys formalise the findings in the comments as an answer so that other users with the same issues can figure out what is going on easily? Otherwise I will do it as a community wiki.

Comment: I am also getting the following error when trying to save the file in Apps Script : ```Error: Line 3: Unexpected token = (line 2021, file "esprima.browser.js-bundle.js")Dismiss```

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Yup the response from the bug team working on this at the moment is private member variables are not supported yet. Based on my experience, any member variable not declared in the constructor is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

At the moment **private member variables are not supported**.

Moreover, as a broad recommendation from the original poster, any member variable should be declared in the constructor of the class.

> *This solution was brought to you by the original poster and those users that participated in the comment section*